# How do I do a time complexity analysis for my get method?

Tags: java, time-complexity

How would I do a time complexity analysis for my get() method?

```
    private DNode find(int index)
    {
        DNode curr = head;  // alias
        
        // Conditional Statements - if the index is in the first half of the list, loop forward to find
        if(index >= 0 && index <= size()/2)
        {
            // For loop - indexes the reference result to the next node
            for(int skip = 0; skip < index; skip++)
            {
                curr = curr.getNext();
            }
        }
        // Otherwise, loop backwards in the list
        else
        {
            // For loop - indexes the reference result to the back node
            for(int skip = 0; skip < index; skip--)
            {
                curr = curr.getBack();
            }
        }
        
        return curr;  // The item at the specified index for the node
    }


    public Object get(int index) throws ListIndexOutOfBoundsException
    {
        // Conditional Statements - checks if index is valid
        if(isValid(index))
        {
            DNode result = find(index);
            return result.getItem();
        }
        
        throw new ListIndexOutOfBoundsException("Out of bounds");
    }
```

How do I test for the best, worst, and average cases for time complexity?  I'm a little confused on how I analyze for this.

EDIT: I've added my find() method

Comment: You need to post `find` method too.

Comment: I've just updated with my find() method

Comment: Your find-implementation is wrong (look at the second for loop, closely).

Comment: Try looking at [How to find time complexity of an algorithm?](https://adrianmejia.com/how-to-find-time-complexity-of-an-algorithm-code-big-o-notation/)